# Сидорова коза

Tags: фразеология

Есть русское выражение "Драть, как Сидорову козу" (причем, с ударением на О - кОзу), то есть, нещадно бить кого-то.
Я читала где-то, что "Сидорова коза" - это искаженное арабское выражение, но подробностей не помню. Правда ли это, и если да, что это за выражение и какое отношение оно имеет, во-первых, к козе, а во-вторых, к жертве побоев?

Answer (score 2):

"Арабская" версия годится только для отчаянных фантазеров типа Вашкевича, который любое русское слово может вывести из арабского.Только вот реальных связей между внутренним миром русских бытовых пословиц и арабским шариатским судом нет никаких. Фонетическое сходство - не доказательство.
Угроза "выдрать как сидорову козу" звучит весьма внушительно, особенно для детей. Легко можно представить, как хозяин, поймавши на своём огороде чужую соседскую козу, стегал её за потраву от всей души плетью или просто веревкой. Нашкодившего человека наказывали примерно так же, не особо разбираясь : попался - получи по полной программе.
В.М.Мокиенко подробно разбирает в своей книге ("Почему мы так говорим") и козу, и Сидора-соседа.

[image]
[Почему мы так говорим?](https://books.google.ru/books?id=U1sFV4alppIC&pg=PA242&lpg=PA241&focus=viewport&dq=%D1%81%D0%B8%D0%B4%D0%BE%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B2%D1%83+%D0%BA%D0%BE%D0%B7%D1%83&hl=ru&output=html_text)

Comment: Вашкевич не фантазер, просто заблуждается. Ведется на официальную хронологию и библейские сказки с историей. Однако арабское зебра - это русский забор, жирафа - журавль. "Совпадения" такого рода из русского в арабский, не одиночные, а массовые, что Вашкевич и отмечает.

Comment: по полной программе пороли на "кОзлах", приспособа такая о четырех ногах и двумя парами рогов, к которым ноги с руками НАКАЗЫВАЕМОГО привязывали. Каз - корень. И слов с этим таким корнем немало.
Сидорами в старые добрые времена называли дворников, а дворниками служили отставные солдаты, а сидор - солдатский вещмешок. А еще дворники как раз и пороли.  
А вот козу пойди да поймай, чтоб выпороть. Стеганешь - пожалеешь и поимеешь рогами или копытом.

Comment: Не уловил смысла вообще. Так это **кОзлы** драли, на которых дворник Сидор дрова пилил и в солдатский вещмешок складывал? Ну, дела...

Comment: дела, это в суде. КОз(ж)у со спины драли на кОзлах. А сидор не имя, а кличка.
а дрова пилите сами.

Comment: >М. Е. Салтыков-Щедрин. Сатиры в прозе (1859-1862)
>Глуповец любит пригибаться к земле и **прикидываться сидоровой козой**, но он помнит.

Приспособа, на которой наказывали провинившихся, называлась просто *козёлъ*, в бурсах и школах это были обыкновенные скамьи на четырёх ножках. Нынешние школьники через козла прыгают. Никто скамейки не называл никогда сидоровыми козами, нет таких свидетельств. Драли не скамьи, а виноватых заодно с невинными.

Comment:  а скамья не кОзлы. А пороли во дворе, а не в кабинете. сидоровой козой,это снять штаны или задрать рубаху прогнувшись.

Comment: сидорову кОзу, к козе никакого отношения,  это спина исполосованная, кожа на спине.  А  с ударением путаница  и созвучно при написании(ударение не ставится) с козой.

Comment: Дедушка Крылов позавидовал бы таким басням, ей-богу.

Answer (score 1):

Имеется много версий:

1.Был такой Сидор,скупой и злой, который и собственную козу не пожалеет, если та заберется в огород и разорит грядки, к примеру.

2.Коза считалась животным вредного нрава, за что, собственно, по представлениям наших предков, она и заслуживала порки. И ведь действительно козам нередко доставалось за потраву.

3.По другой версии,сидорова коза» – это искажение арабского оборота «садар каза», означавшего приговор шариатского судьи – кази, или казия – и  содержавший в себе наказание осужденному в виде битья палками. Арабское слово «каза» означает, кроме того, и само судопроизводство, точнее, рассмотрение отдельных судебных дел, случаев.

4.На польском языке «koza» обозначает карцер. У поляков, кстати, в аналогичном присловье предусматривается и другое действие, и другой объект: «drapac' jak Sidor owu kosu», что переводится: «чесать, как Сидор ту косу».

5.В русском языке козой называли не только рогатую животину. У В.Даля, например, можем прочитать, что это и девка резвая, и игра в догонялки, и волынка из козьей шкуры, и рычаг для смазки карет и повозок, и наплечные носилки каменщиков, и тренога-светильник у рыбаков, промышляющих лучением рыбы, и крестьян, которым приходилось молотить зерно в ночную пору, и клок хлеба, оставленного на пашне несжатым (таким образом, некрасовские строчки «только не сжата полоска одна, грустную думу наводит она» – о козе). Но «козу» на поле оставляли и специально, по обычаю, причем не только славяне, у которых было принято считать ее подношением «Велесу на бородку», но и, например, в южной Германии, согласно сообщению Д.Фрезера в его знаменитой «Золотой ветви». На последнем снопе иногда даже помещали изображение козла или козы.

6.Предполагают и  что начало фразеологизму было положено вполне конкретным историческим лицом, боярином Сидором Ковылой-Висловым, который якобы дружил с великим князем московским и владимирским Василием Дмитриевичем. Будто бы известен был сей боярин склонностью к скотоложству, откуда и пошло соответствующее выражение… Впрочем, версия эта не выдерживает никакой исторической проверки.

http://shkolazhizni.ru/archive/0/n-23023/

Comment: "drapac' jak Sidor owu kosu" - попробуйте переведите  эту фразу с помощью он-лайн переводчиков, поглядите, что получится. Хотя в Интернете версия с этой якобы польской фразой довольно распространена. А потом сделайте обратный перевод предлагаемого перевода - и Вы увидите, что и с падежом ошибка, и с именем(по-польски Sydir), и вообще это что-то не то.

Comment: как и у монахов средневековья, это результат как бездумного копирования, так и прочтения без знания языка по написанному другим шрифтом, с переводом частями.
drapak-царапать,koza-коза. Вот так кальки и получаются.